# Find a surface that has positive constant curvature that is not open subset of sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Can some one find a surface that has positive constant curvature that is not open subset of sphere.

I know every connected and compact surface with positive constant curvature is sphere.

I need some hint. Thanks a lot indeed

Comment: Physical experience shows that if you take a small piece of the sphere, let's say everything north of the $80^\circ$ northern latitude line, that surface may be flexed in 3-space, distorting its embedding without distorting its intrinsic metric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** You can write down the expression for the Gaussian curvature of a general surface of revolution. For example, assume it's obtained by rotating the arclength parametrized curve $x=f(s)$, $z=g(s)$ about the $z$-axis. Then you should be able to show that $f''(s)+Kf(s)=0$. You will get plenty of surfaces of constant curvature (including, but not limited to, spheres).